# Dictionaries and Hash Tables in MS-Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm want to use either a hash table or a dictionary in my access program. Apparently, I'm supposed to be using the Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library for this, but it doesn't work.

```
Dim Dict1 As Dictionary

' Create a dictionary instance.
Set Dict1 = New Dictionary
```

It can't find the methods ".compareMode" or ".Add":

```
With Dict1
  'set compare mode
  .CompareMode = BinaryCompare
  ' Add items to the dictionary.
  .Add 1, "Item 1"
  .Add 2, "Item 2"
  .Add 3, "Item 3"
End With
```

Instead, these are the only one avaiable to me:

```
.application
.creator
.delete
etc...
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all change *BinaryCompare* to *vbBinaryCompare*.

And I think you want to be doing your set like this:

```
Set Dict1 = CreateObject(Scripting.Dictionary)
```

**Edit** Just so that it is more visible, here is Anton's eventual solution. He changed the way he declared his dictionary as follows:

```
Dim SortValues As Scripting.Dictionary 
Set SortValues = New Scripting.Dictionary
```

Comment: That way didn't work, however it gave me an idea.

    Dim SortValues As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set SortValues = New Scripting.Dictionary

That worked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: CodeSlave's original line should have put the class name (Scripting.Dictionary) in double quotes i.e. 

Dim Dict1 As Object
Set Dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")